# how to have global variables in MVC views

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, global-variables

I am working on a MVC project.

In the view, I have `$(".Fee").click();` in the javascript. The `$(".Fee")` selector will use in many views. So I think if I can have a global variable, like string `f = ".Fee";` then I can use `$(f)` instead of `$(".Fee")`. so if I change the element's class name, I don't have to change all selectors in many views.

But is this achievable and how can I do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I don't think that you are going to gain much at all by having a global constants that you use for your selectors. It's more likely just going to make the code harder to read. But opinions aside, I would strongly encourage you to place these constants in a javascript file that you include in your Layout page.

My reasoning is that declaring these constants in a CS file just to template them out in javascript in your views is kludgy and unnecessary when you are dealing in the world of javascript at the point of usage. Might as well leverage javascript the entire way for simplicity and clarity.

**SelectorConstants.js file (included in Layout page)**

```
var SelectorConstants = {
     Fee: '.Fee',
     AnotherSelector: 'some string'
};
```

Then in your views you can declare a local variable that is much briefer without running the risk of naming conflicts and/or verbosity:

**View**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/SelectorConstants.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var sel = SelectorConstants;
    $(sel.Fee);
</script>
```